# Is possible make a .xcodeproj file and how?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

is possible make a .xcodeproj file and how? I'd like to make a Mac software which have to build a .xcodeproj file.

Comment: You don't need a `.xcodeproj` to build Mac software. This is needed just for Xcode. It is like you don't need a `.csproj` to build C# programs either. This is needed just for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An xcode project file is just a keyed archive of internal xcode model objects.  It'd be a waste of time trying to generate one outside of xcode.

If you want to build a compile script your best option is to generate Makefiles.  Those can be imported in xcode if you need this to work with the IDE as well.

Comment: Thanks guy! You give me an idea for my project :D

Answer (score 1):

Install Xcode from developer.apple.com.  Open Xcode and select "New Project..." from the File menu.